# Golang slice reference confusion

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    values := make([]int, 0, 100)
    val := make([][]int, 2)
    for i:=0; i<2; i++ {
        values = values[:0]
        for j:=0; j<2; j++ {
            values = append(values, i+j)
        }
        val[i] = values
        fmt.Println(values, val) //
    }
    fmt.Println(val)
}
```

---

https://play.golang.org/p/5x60VfDXbFw

when appending slice，val is expected to be [[0, 1], [1, 2]], but got [[1,2], [1,2]]

Comment: That's not the result I saw on go play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the slice `val` contains pointers to its subslices, rather than the subslices themselves. In your code, you initially place a pointer to `values` in positions `val[0]`. Then you modify `values` and then set a pointer to `values` in `val[1]`. But both `val[0]` and `val[1]` point to the same underlying object (`values`), which has been modified.

You can fix this by creating a new `values` slice on each iteration of the outer loop, this way each sub slice of `val` will be a different slice.

For example:

```
func main() {
    val := make([][]int, 2)
    for i:=0; i<2; i++ {
        values := make([]int, 0, 100)
        for j:=0; j<2; j++ {
            values = append(values, i+j)
        }
        val[i] = values
        fmt.Println(values, val) //
    }
    fmt.Println(val)
}
```

Output from `fmt.Println`:

```
[0 1] [[0 1] []]    // values, val
[1 2] [[0 1] [1 2]] // values, val
[[0 1] [1 2]]       // val
```

Answer (score 1):

slice feature in go:

> Slices hold references to an underlying array, and if you assign one
>   slice to another, both refer to the same array.

The value of slice will be the last time you modify it. Thus, here's two approach to achieve the goal.

use **copy**

```
func main() {
    values := make([]int, 0, 100)
    val := make([][]int, 2)
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        values = values[:0]
        for j := 0; j < 2; j++ {
            values = append(values, i+j)
        }
        val[i] = make([]int, 2)
        copy(val[i], values)
        fmt.Println(values, val) //
    }
    fmt.Println(val)
}
```

new values slice in first for-loop each time

```
val := make([][]int, 2)
for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    values := make([]int, 0, 2)
    for j := 0; j < 2; j++ {
        values = append(values, i+j)
    }
    val[i] = values
    fmt.Println(values, val) //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize values in your for loop, `values = []int{}`

code like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var (
        valLength = 2
    )
    val := make([][]int, valLength)
    for i := 0; i < valLength; i++ {
        values := []int{}
        for j := 0; j < 2; j++ {
            values = append(values, i+j)
        }
        val[i] = values
        fmt.Println(values, val) //
    }
    fmt.Println(val)
}
```

And you only change variable `valLength` to get any length of slice you want.